# Python: Using RDFLIB to graph a Sesame database

Tags: python, graph, graph-databases, sesame, rdflib

Is it possible to draw a graph of a Sesame RDF database using RDFLIB? 
This is what I tried:

```
endpoint = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/openrdf-workbench/repositories/movies/explore?resource=%3Cfile%3A%2F%2Fmovies_export.rdf%3E"

from rdflib import Graph
g = Graph()
g.parse(endpoint)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Software\rdflib\movieGraph.py", line 10, in <module>
    g.parse(endpoint)
  File "c:\python26_32bit\lib\site-packages\rdflib\graph.py", line 756, in parse

    parser = plugin.get(format, Parser)()
  File "c:\python26_32bit\lib\site-packages\rdflib\plugin.py", line 89, in get
    raise PluginException("No plugin registered for (%s, %s)" % (name, kind))
rdflib.plugin.PluginException: No plugin registered for (application/xml, <class
 'rdflib.parser.Parser'>)
```

I think the only trick is specifying a proper URL to cause Sesame to return a .rdf xml layout.

Author of question: reposted to [http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/9414/python-using-rdflib-to-graph-a-sesame-database](http://web.archive.org/web/20130830191313/http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/9414/python-using-rdflib-to-graph-a-sesame-database) (see answer there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endpoint URL is wrong. It points to the Sesame Workbench, which is not a (SPARQL) endpoint, but a client application. The SPARQL endpoint for any Sesame database is always on the Sesame server, and is equal to the repository URL. In your case, probably `http://127.0.0.1:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/movies`.

Looking at what you're doing, I think you do not need a SPARQL endpoint but just want an export of the complete Sesame database. For this, you can use `http://127.0.0.1:8080/openrdf-sesame/repositories/movies/statements`. See the [Sesame HTTP communication protocol](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/system.docbook?view#The_Sesame_REST_HTTP_Protocol) for more details.

(answer copied from my own answer on another site, posted here for completeness)

Comment: Thanks, as the question was 3 years ago, I'm no longer working with that tool.  I'll mark the as answer, but I cannot verify.